# Optimize MariaDB - avoid "Copying to tmp table" - find joins without index

Tags: performance, mariadb

I have a website which is backed by a MariaDB database. The DB seems to be the bottleneck to the sites performance. I spend quite some time on optimizing various DB parameters, but now I am stuck with a lot of "Copying to tmp table" operations and joins without index.

**Any idea on how to avoid them? Or how to optimize the DB?**

The DB uses only InnoDB tables.

---

If I use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to look at the current queries, there seem to be no slow queries. All queries show a time of 0-1 seconds. I had this on auto refresh every second, and not a single query reached 2 seconds.
I also tried manually running some of the "slow" 1 second queries and they all finish within 1 - 1.5 seconds.

While looking at `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` I can see that many queries are in the `Copying to tmp table` state. I deduct from that, that this process step is probably the slowest. What causes it? How can I avoid it?

The DB is ~8 GB and everything should fit into RAM.

The queries also produce small results (e.g., 5 rows). Using `explain` also only shows a maximum of <100 rows.

---

I optimized the DB settings with mysqltuner.pl. Everything got faster, but I am still stuck with a lot of joins without index (according to mysqltuner). I don't know how to find them.
I tried looking for frequent queries with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and took a look at them. All joins use indexed columns.

---

Some othe hints from mysqltuner where I don't know how to adress them:

```
...
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/3M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 0% (34/15954)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00% (0/34999)
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 41.4% (2M cached / 5M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 21506680
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 321K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 127051
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 21% (81K on disk / 373K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 91% (2K created / 34K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (200 hits / 23K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (1024) is greater than number of tables (629)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (5/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (5M immediate / 5M locks)
...
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 12.0G / 8.1G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.5G * 2/12.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 12
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (3911916061 hits / 3912183382 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 61.91% (60693 hits / 98030 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 37337 writes)
```

---

Here is an example query.
The query is generated. I know that the query itself could be better, but I can not change the software.

```
SELECT
    product.id as __product_id,
    variant.id as __variant_id,
    variant.ordernumber as __variant_ordernumber
FROM
    s_articles product
INNER JOIN s_articles_details variant ON
    variant.id = product.main_detail_id
    AND variant.active = 1
    AND product.active = 1
INNER JOIN s_articles_categories_ro productCategory ON
    productCategory.articleID = product.id
    AND productCategory.categoryID IN (3156292)
LEFT JOIN s_articles_avoid_customergroups avoidCustomerGroup ON
    avoidCustomerGroup.articleID = product.id
    AND avoidCustomerGroup.customerGroupId IN (4)
INNER JOIN s_articles_categories similarMain ON
    similarMain.articleID = product.id
    AND similarMain.articleID != '435'
INNER JOIN s_articles_categories similarSub ON
    similarSub.categoryID = similarMain.categoryID
    AND similarMain.articleID != similarSub.articleID
    AND similarSub.articleID = '435'
LEFT JOIN s_articles_top_seller_ro topSeller ON
    topSeller.article_id = product.id
INNER JOIN s_articles_attributes productAttribute ON
    productAttribute.articledetailsID = variant.id
WHERE
    avoidCustomerGroup.articleID IS NULL
GROUP BY
    product.id
ORDER BY
    topSeller.sales ASC,
    variant.id ASC
LIMIT 5
```

this is the explain for that

```
id|select_type|table             |type  |possible_keys                                                                         |key             |key_len|ref                              |rows|Extra                                       |
--+-----------+------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+-------+---------------------------------+----+--------------------------------------------+
 1|SIMPLE     |similarSub        |ref   |articleID,categoryID,articleID_2                                                      |articleID       |4      |const                            |  12|Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort|
 1|SIMPLE     |similarMain       |ref   |articleID,categoryID,articleID_2                                                      |categoryID      |4      |devdb.similarSub.categoryID      |  62|Using where                                 |
 1|SIMPLE     |product           |eq_ref|PRIMARY,main_detailID,product_newcomer,get_category_filters,s_articles_active_IDX     |PRIMARY         |4      |devdb.similarMain.articleID      |   1|Using where                                 |
 1|SIMPLE     |topSeller         |eq_ref|article_id                                                                            |article_id      |4      |devdb.similarMain.articleID      |   1|                                            |
 1|SIMPLE     |productCategory   |ref   |articleID,categoryID,articleID_2,categoryID_2,category_id_by_article_id,elastic_search|articleID       |8      |devdb.similarMain.articleID,const|   1|Using index                                 |
 1|SIMPLE     |productAttribute  |ref   |articledetailsID                                                                      |articledetailsID|5      |devdb.product.main_detail_id     |   1|Using index                                 |
 1|SIMPLE     |variant           |eq_ref|PRIMARY,s_articles_details_id_IDX                                                     |PRIMARY         |4      |devdb.product.main_detail_id     |   1|Using where                                 |
 1|SIMPLE     |avoidCustomerGroup|eq_ref|PRIMARY,articleID                                                                     |PRIMARY         |8      |devdb.similarMain.articleID,const|   1|Using where; Using index; Not exists        |
```

Comment: "Copying to tmp table" -- Show us a query that has such, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  The cure may be as simple as adding a composite index.

Comment: composite index you say. Maybe that's the hint. If I have a `select * from a join b on a.x = b.x and a.y = b.y` and table a has an index for x and another index for y. And table b as well. Does this join use an index? Or do I need to have a composite `x , y` index in table a and table b?

Answer (score 1):

`Using index` says that the Optimizer could use the index, by itself, to reach into the table.  This is usually optimal.  (It may or may not be a "composite" index.)

These indexes may be optimal:

```
product:  INDEX(main_detail_id, id,  active)
productCategory:  INDEX(articleID,  categoryID)
avoidCustomerGroup:  INDEX(articleID,  customerGroupId)
similarMain:  INDEX(articleID,  categoryID)
similarSub:  INDEX(categoryID,  articleID)
topSeller:  INDEX(article_id,  sales)
productAttribute:  INDEX(articledetailsID)
```

(Without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I cannot tell if you already have such indexes.  Nor can I advise further on whether the "x,y" discussed below applies.)

`IN (3156292)` is the same as `= 3156292`.  But `IN (22, 33)` is harder to optimize.

The unrelated `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` lead to two temp tables and two sorts of them.

```
INNER JOIN ...
        ON  variant.id = product.main_detail_id  -- relation
       AND  variant.active = 1    -- filter
       AND  product.active = 1    -- filter
```

Please move the "filtering" to `WHERE`; this could help me (and others) in analyzing how to speed up the query.  Caveat:  `LEFT JOIN` may need the filtering in the ON clause.

One performance technique is to turn the query inside out to get finished with the `LIMIT 5` *before* all the JOINs.  Something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... -- as little as possible
            FROM product
            JOIN variant ON ...
            LEFT JOIN topseller ON ...
            WHERE ...
            GROUP BY ...
            ORDER BY ...
            LIMIT ...
         ) AS x
     JOIN ...  -- the other tables
     JOIN ...  -- and possibly the original tables (to get more cols)
     ORDER BY ...   -- repeated
     -- (no LIMIT needed)
```

(With the relationships and filters mixed together, I don't want to attempt to provide details on this possible optimization.)

What I see in that partial tuner output:

- Turn off the Query Cache
- The buffer_pool is a good size (until the dataset grows a lot more)
- Set `long_query_time = 1`; collect for a day; then use `pt-query-digest` to see which queries are the naughtiest.  This won't lead to *all* the "joins without indexes", but it will lead to the *important* ones.

Re your Comment about 'composite' indexes:

- Yes, *for the given example*, `INDEX(x,y)` (in either order) is better than `INDEX(x), INDEX(y)`.
- If you have `INDEX(x,y)`, you do not need `INDEX(x)`, but you *may* still need some index starting with `y`.
- More:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into it. The Index Cookbook is also quite helpful. I tried turning off the query cache, but this resulted in a higher CPU load. So I will leave it on for now.

Comment: @masgo - Keep your eye on the QC.  In _most_ cases, it is not worth having.  In _some_ cases it even causes more CPU.  Recommend adding `SQL_NO_CACHE` to `SELECTs` that won't benefit from the QC.  Another caveat:  If you ever move to any form of clustering or to 8.0, the QC will not be available.